# How to insert entity with foreign keys defined as Long in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.8 and I have a table defined in mysql (5.5) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    version INT(11),
    description VARCHAR(60),
    scheduled_at DATETIME,
    `from` BIGINT(20),
    `to` BIGINT(20),
    deleted BIT(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    completed BIT(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    delete_from_after_completion BIT(1) DEFAULT b'0',
    CONSTRAINT FK14F71A73C588I54F FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES other_table (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK14F71C231C45J198 FOREIGN KEY (`to`) REFERENCES other_table (id)
);
CREATE INDEX FK14F71A73C588I54F ON mytable (`from`);
CREATE INDEX FK14F71C231C45J198 ON mytable (`to`);
```

And a Java entity defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "scheduled_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "SM")
    private Date scheduledAt;
    @Column(name = "from")
    private Long fromId;
    @Column(name = "to")
    private Long toId;
    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted;
    @Column(name = "completed")
    private boolean completed;
    @Column(name = "delete_from_after_completion")
    private boolean deleteFromEntityAfterCompletion;

    ...
}
```

When I try to `persist` an instance of `MyTable` with valid values I end up with the following error:

```
2016-01-12 10:06:33,443 [qtp2139431292-20] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2016-01-12 10:06:33,443 [qtp2139431292-20] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, scheduled_at, to, version) values (0, 1, 0, 'Test', 10, '2016-01-13 00:00:' at line 1
```

I suspect that the problem occurs since I try to model the foreign key relationships (`to` and `from`) as `Long` instead of an entity (`OtherTable`). I suspect this because Hibernate can indeed persist this entity if I comment out the `to` and `from` fields. Note that the relationship to the `to` and `from` entities does indeed exists in the database so that's not the problem.

If I try insert manually using something like this it works:

```
insert into mytable values(3, 0, "desc", '2016-10-10 00:00:', 10, 11, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a column that is a SQL reserved keyword ("`from`") and Hibernate doesn't bother quoting it for you. Other JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus JPA) take care of such things for you. You will have to add single quotes around the reserved word in your JPA annotation information

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem is not a matter of persisting Long values.

Your code has something wrong. I bet there is a wrong quotation mark in your insert code.

Comment: I'm not writing the insert statement by hand, Hibernate does this.

Comment: So I guess it's better to post more code. Your repository class and where you are calling insert method.
Have a nice day.

Comment: @neil-stockton's answer was correct, the problem was the escaping. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No problem =) @Johan